# Is the 4th root of $3^3$ $3^3/4$ or $2.2795$?

Tags: exponentiation

I'm working through a textbook and one question is:

> Use a calculator to find the value of the following expression: $$\sqrt[\large4]{3^3}$$

The textbook answer is given as $2.2795$; however, using https://live.sympy.org/, if I enter `root(3**3, 4)`, I get back `3^3/4`.

How do I arrive at $2.2795$?

---

Here's the original question and the given solution:

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I put it into simpy it is clearly $3^{(\frac 34)}$ as it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$3^{\frac{3}{4}}$ is what you get out. Not $\frac{3^3}{4}$. As it happens, $3^\frac{3}{4}$ is approximately 2.2795.

Comment: Ah so it's the same. Thanks, accepting when the limit comes off.